# Android Recycler view Scroll bar

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview

How to get scroll bar in recycler view ?
I am developing an Image gallery application where images are loaded in recycler view. So I want a have a scroll bar where while scrolling date of capture can be shown.

Somewhat similar to this (date instead of letters):- [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/recyclerview-fastscroll-part-1/) blog post by Mark Allison should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for solution.

Comment: Only thing is that how to get date in the bubble?

Comment: Should be able to accomplish that by changing the bubble view from an `ImageView` to a `TextView` (using the same background).

Comment: If this was able to solve your problem, be sure to mark the answer as accepted as well. Hope it helped!

Comment: This link is for recyclerview with linearlayout. What if I have gridlayout in recyclerview

Comment: Code should be added to the answer in order to prevent the link from getting corrupted and therefore invalidating it in the future.