# Flutter: how to make a custom Scrollbar as in Google photos app?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a gallery with scroll as in Google Photos.
How to make a custom Scrollbar?
Do I need for this create my Scrollbar class with ScrollbarPainter where I will draw image with arrows and tooltip with date?
Will it be draggable by default or it should implement Draggable?

[image: Scrollbar as in Google photos app]

Comment: Honestly, this is almost like asking for a complete application. I think that this feature "request" is way too broad.

Comment: Hi @Marica and welcome to stack overflow! This question is a little bit broad in its scope. Generally, rather than asking for a solution to a problem this complex, people are encouraged to get as far as they can, and then post the relevant part of their code along with a more specific query, rather than asking others to implement an entire chunk of an application. Also, without knowing how you've structured your list of photos (if you have), it's a little bit difficult to figure out how to hook that up to the scrollbar.

Comment: @rmtmckenzieyeah, it's really a new feature that is not in flutter yet. I was thinking may be it's already exist but I failed to find.

So far now I managed to draw my image as a scrollbar. For this I create a copy of Scrollbar, ScrollbarState and ScrollbarPainter. And last one is drawing
`canvas.drawImage(scrollImage, thumbOrigin, _paint);`

Also I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482762/android-recycler-view-scroll-bar) here about fast scrolling in Android. And in flutter there is no widget for fast scrolling yet.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/creating-draggable-scrollbar-in-flutter-a0ae8cf3143b

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing plugins like [flexible_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/flexible_scrollbar/) to create a custom scrollbar easily. Update the child widget being returned by `FlexibleScrollbar.scrollLabelBuilder()` to update the scroll label according to the scroll's current position on the Grid.

```
FlexibleScrollbar(
  controller: scrollController,
  scrollLabelBuilder: (info) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double cellSize =
        (isVertical ? screenSize.width : screenSize.height) / 3;
    final int lineNum =
        (scrollController.position.pixels ~/ cellSize) + 1;
    return AnimatedContainer(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(info.isDragging ? 1 : 0.6),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      duration: animationDuration,
      child: Text(
                'Row: $lineNum',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  child: GridView.builder(),
  ...
)
```

Check the sample code [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flexible_scrollbar/example) to try it out.